# Sinch Verification With .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, sinch

I am trying to use the Sinch Verification service to verify a phone number as a part of my web application's registration process.  I give the users the option to verify by SMS or by phone call.  SMS messages seem straight forward with the examples from github since I can just report the verification by presenting the user with a form to enter the code on, but I am having trouble deciphering how a callout verification works.  Seems like I need to wait for a callback of the VerificationResultEvent?  Or do I need to be polling for the callout verification to complete?

UPDATE:

I started verification like this:

```
var response = await _api.Verification(phoneNumber).Initiate(VerificationMethod.Callout);
```

Response does not have CLI value in response.Callout, only in response.FlashCall.

Report verification:

```
var response = await _api.Verification(phoneNumber).WithCli("????????").Report(VerificationMethod.Callout);
```

Or do I not need to report verification for a callout?  Just wait for Callback event?

Comment: WE will post the result to you when someone enters the code and you call report verificaton to our rest api, are you using the Javascript sdk for the client side?

Comment: Updated above with sample.  I am using server side calls to initiate callout, easier with ASPNET application to track everything that way.  Do I need to report verification for callouts?  The CLI the documentation says is required is not in the callout response, seems like I shouldn't need to report verification for a callout since the phone call would just trigger the callback event

Comment: Call outs should not require a report that's roght

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification